# Date.parse(new Date()) javascript time format in C#

Tags: c#

"Date.parse(new Date())" time format in javascript

eg return value:1372843260000

I want in C# Code but i have try the code below seem like not the correct value/format that i want .
eg return value:1372780800000

```
 double DateTimeMIll = ConvertToTimestamp(DateTime.Today.Date);

public static double ConvertToTimestamp(DateTime date)
{
    DateTime origin = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    TimeSpan diff = date.ToUniversalTime() - origin;
    return Math.Floor(diff.TotalMilliseconds);
}
```

I know is hard to get what i mean please help me out.

Comment: Your code is odd in a few ways, but it works for me - I'd be very surprised to see the return value you're getting. Please show a short but complete console program with actual output.

Comment: Are you using Windows XP?

Comment: So, what is the value returned by `ConvertToTimestamp` in your code sample?

Answer (score 0):

```
double DateTimeMIll = ConvertToTimestamp(DateTime.Today.Date);

public static double ConvertToTimestamp(DateTime date)
{
        DateTime origin = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        double asd = (date - origin).TotalMilliSeconds;
        return asd;
}
```

i hope this might help you....

Comment: what is the class for Duration?

Comment: Do you mean `TimeSpan asd = (date - origin).Duration();`? Either way this doesn't work

Comment: i think the problem is result comming is too long for int so try taking it as long ...  i have updated the answer please check..

Comment: This doesn't return the value that the OP wants: `1372780800000`